# Call an event in code that is specified in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, click

Good evening. I've looked at everything I can on Google and cannot find what I'm looking for (or I am not searching correctly). Thanks ahead of time for the help.

In XAML, on a ContentControl, I have MouseDoubleClick="ControlClick".

This ContentControl does not have a single mouse click event. So I added one in code. When that single-mouse-click event in code is called, I would like to call the MouseDoubleClick event defined on the ControlConrol in XAML.

In the single-click mouse event, I have the ControlControl object (I'll call it "c"). There is a ContentControl.MouseDoubleClick handler but I do not know how to invoke it.

How may I? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `ContentControl` does have single mouse button click events: `MouseButtonDown` and `MouseButtonUp`, depending when you'd like to handle the action.

Then, to invoke a `MouseDoubleClick` event in your single click event handler, you'd call the following:

```
(sender as ContentControl).RaiseEvent(new MouseButtonEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.ChangedButton) { RoutedEvent = MouseDoubleClickEvent });
```

where `sender` is the `object` and `e` is the `MouseButtonEventArgs e` of the single click event.

You must remember that double clicking will now invoke two single click events (which invoke the double clicking in turn) and a double click event, thus the double click event handler will effectively be called trice.
You can protect against this behaviour by checking the `TimeStamp` property of the `MouseButtonEventArgs` and ignoring the incoming event in the handler if the timespan between the clicks is too short.